# Unexpected auto deref behavior

Tags: rust, dereference

when tried impl a double linked list in rust, i found below unexpected error

```rust
if let Some(link) = self.tail.take() {
    let x = link.borrow_mut();
    link.borrow_mut().next = Some(node.clone());
} else { ... }
```

here link is inferred to be `Rc<RefCell<Node<..>>>` and compiler says:

> Cannot borrow immutable local variable `link` as mutable.

After tried, I guess when `use std::borrow::BorrowMut`, the error occurs.

```rust
// compiles
fn test1() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(1));
    let b = RefCell::new(1);
    b.borrow_mut();
    a.borrow_mut();
}

// doesn't compile
fn test2() {
    use std::borrow::BorrowMut; // inserted this import!

    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(1));
    let b = RefCell::new(1);
    b.borrow_mut();
    a.borrow_mut();
}
```

here `test2()` fails to be compiled. I wanna know why it works this way.

Comment: Minimal WORKING code example would be helpful. You can use [rust play](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to share it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you *want* to call is the method [`RefCell::borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut).

However, `a` is a `Rc` and not a `RefCell`, so it has no `borrow_mut` method. This is where auto-dereferencing enters the picture. Because `Rc<RefCell<T>>` implements the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait, it can be automatically dereferenced to a `&RefCell<T>` at method calls, and that's exactly what happens in the first test.

Now, if we import the `BorrowMut` trait, the test stops working. This is because the `BorrowMut` trait also has a method called `borrow_mut`, which is [implemented for all types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/borrow.rs.html#220-224):

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized> BorrowMut<T> for T { ... }
```

This means that there is now a `borrow_mut` method available for `Rc`, so no auto-dereferencing occurs, and our code calls the wrong method.

The most comprehensive explanation of how auto-dereferencing works is in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules/28552082#28552082).